# How to navigate to the profile page in Communities using lightning:navigation?

Tags: lightning-community, url, lightningnavigation

I tried constructing PageReference following documentation - [pageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm):

```
  handleGoToProfile: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // const pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    const pageReference = {
      type: "comm__namedPage",
      attributes: {
        pageName: "profile/{recordId}",
        recordId: $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")
      }
    };

    const navService = cmp.find("navService");
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
  }
```

Once I click the button

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{! c.handleGoToProfile }">Go To Profile </button>
```

I am redirected to this usl:

> /s/profile%2F%7BrecordId%7D

Is it possible to redirect to the profile page at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to pass along a recordId, you need to set page type as `standard__recordPage` like this:

```
   handleGoToProfile: function(cmp, event, helper) {

        const pageReference = {
          type: "standard__recordPage",
          attributes: {
            pageName: "profile",
            recordId: $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id"),
            actionName: "view"
          }
        };

        const navService = cmp.find("navService");
        event.preventDefault(); 
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
      }
```

Comment: This doesn't go to profile but user record detail page as record Id is current user's Id, When passing profile id, it works fine.

Comment: @Raul Not sure to really understand your comment. From a community perspective, the profile page is the community user's profile page, so we need to specify the user record id in this case.

Comment: You're right, I got it confused. Great answer!